# Bash-script, cut the line and paste to next

Tags: linux, bash, line

I'm new to linux and don't know how to solve my issue. I have an output like this (about 200 lines):

```
Peter Griffin
222
Vasya Pupkin
333
```

I need to convert this to:

```
222, Peter Griffin
333, Vasya Pupkin
```

I tried

```
ldapsearch -LLL -D $bindDN -w $password -p $port -h $host -b $searchBase -S "telephoneNumber" -s sub cn telephoneNumber | grep -v "dn: " | grep "\\n" | awk -F": " '{ print $2 }'
```

How can I realize it?

Comment: Please show your coding efforts.

Comment: ldapsearch -LLL -D $bindDN -w $password -p $port -h $host -b $searchBase -S "telephoneNumber" -s sub cn telephoneNumber | grep -v "dn: " | grep "\\n" | awk -F": " '{ print $2 }'

Comment: after this, i have an output like in thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in `Awk` alone,

```
awk '{getline nextLine; print nextLine,$0}' OFS="," file
222,Peter Griffin
333,Vasya Pupkin
```

So with your commands, just pipeline the output that produces those lines to the `Awk` above,

```
.. | awk '{getline nextLine; print nextLine,$0}' OFS=","
```

Comment: nice ...............

Comment: Thanks, It works either :)

Answer (score 1):

```
xargs -L2 < inputfile|awk '{x=$NF;$NF=""; print x "," $0 }'
222,Peter Griffin
333,Vasya Pupkin
```

Explanation: `xargs -L2` is to combine two consecutive lines into one. Once the input is changed to single line , feed it to `awk` for column manipulation.

Awk alone solution:

```
awk 'NR%2{x=$0;next} {print $0,",",x}' inputfile
```